# UILongPressGestureRecognizer detect if fingers moved certain radius

Tags: objective-c, ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UILongPressGestureRecognizer setup like this:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                          initWithTarget:self
                                          action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
longPress.numberOfTouchesRequired = 3;
longPress.allowableMovement = 30;
```

In my handleLongPress selector, i'm checking for the 3 states, UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan, UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged, and UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded. Is UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged in any way related to the allowableMovement property? I want to get that state triggered only if a finger has moved more than 30 pixels, but as it is right now, it gets triggered with the slightest movements.

Answer (score 0):

allowableMovement is the maximum movement, not a minimum.  [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILongPressGestureRecognizer/allowableMovement)

Your best bet is to put a check in the method called when any movement is detected, in this check you can discard any calls when the move was less than a certain distance.

The UILongPressGestureRecognizer extends the UIGestureRecognizer which can return the location of the touch every time the handler method gets called, check out [UIGestureRecognizer class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIGestureRecognizer)

Comment: How do I check if the move was less than a certain distance?

Comment: @thisiscrazy4 check out the UIGestureRecognizer it allows you to retrieve touch locations.